# Infinite scroll table w/sorting and filtering

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable, footable

I want to implement an infinite scroll table, that loads chunks of data at a time, I'd like to be able to sort it (the whole table, not just the visible rows) as well as filtering it. To do so I tried Footables plugin, but I can't really achieve what I want, when it loads the data async, it doesn't sort nor filter..

How could I achieve this implementation? I don't mind if it's another library, angular or whatsoever. But I need some fresh air from what I've already tried.

I'll paste the code I have right which loads the data perfectly on scroll, but doesn't sort (it doesn't work apparently with ajax).

Table markup:

```
<table data-sorting="true" class="table table-hover footable" data-page-size="30">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>                   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Js

```
var win = $(window);
win.scroll(function() {
    if(win.scrollTop() + win.height() >= $(document).height()) {
        getData();
    }
});

function getData(){ 
    var container = $('table tbody');
    var displayedElements = container.children('tr').length;
    var ajaxUrl = '/some/api';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: {
            displayedData: displayedElements
        },
        success : function(html) {
            $('table tbody').append(html);
            var page_size = $('table').data('page-size');
            $("table").attr('data-page-size', page_size + 30);
            $('table tbody').trigger('footable_redraw');
        },
        error : function(xhr, statusText, error) { 
            alert("Error! Could not retrieve the data.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you also considered jQuery's [DataTables plugin](https://www.datatables.net/) with [Scroller extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/scroller/), or [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)?

Comment: I've tried it and I've got a problem that I couldn't solve, it loads the whole dataset instead of async loading it while user scrolls, I've followed the documentation but can't get it to work as I want.